# x axis labels overlapping for grouped category bar chart in d3

Tags: d3.js

My requirement is to generate grouped category bar chart. I am able to generate that graph but the problem is if x axis labels names are bigger than bar range band then label names are overlapping.because of this  unable to get good look and feel as  expected.I found some where that we can wrap text labels but I don't know how to achieve that.

here js and html code related to generated grouped category chart

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 130,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 2360 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 560 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var color = {
  Mechanical: '#4A7B9D',
  Electrical: '#54577C',
  Hydraulic: '#ED6A5A'
};
var barPadding = 40;
var data = [
  {
    "key"  : "portFolio1",
    "values"  :[
              {
               "key"  : "project1",
               "values" :[
                         {
                          "key"  : "config1",
                           "values" :[
                                   {
                                    "key" :"date1",
                                    "value": 12
                                   },
                                   {
                                     "key"  : "date2",
                                     "value":  10
                                   },
                                   {
                                     "key"  : "date3",
                                     "value": 2
                                   } 
                              ],
                          
                           },

   {
                          "key"  : "configurationwithvalue",
                           "values" :[
                                   {
                                    "key" :"date1asa",
                                    "value": 10
                                   },
                                   {
                                     "key"  : "date2",
                                     "value":  10
                                   },
                                   {
                                     "key"  : "date3",
                                     "value": 2
                                   } 
                              ],
                            
                           },
                           {
                            "key"  : "config2",
                            "values" :[
                                    {
                                      "key"  : "date1",
                                      "value": 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "key"  : "date3",
                                      "value": 14
                                    }
                                    ],
                                
                             }
                             ],
                          
                    },
                    {
                     "key"  : "projct2",
                     "values" :[
                              {
                                "key"  : "congi1",
                                "values" :[
                                          {
                                           "key"  : "date2",
                                           "value" :1
                                          },
                                          {
                                           "key"  : "date3",
                                            "value": 10
                                           }
                                         ],
                              
                               }
                               ],
                           
                      }
                      ]  ,
       
        },
        {
        "key"  : "portfolio2",
         "values" :[
                   {
                     "key"  : "portfolio2_project1",
                     "values" :[
                               {
                                "key"  : "congie1",
                                "values"  : [
                                         {
                                          "key"  : "date12",
                                          "value": 23
                                         },
                                        {
                                         "key"  : "date1",
                                         "value" : 1
                                       }
                                    ],
                                
                                 }
                              ],
                          
                         }
                     ],
                 
                 },
  {
    "key"  : "portFolio3",
    "values"  :[
              {
               "key"  : "project_portfolio3",
               "values" :[
                         {
                          "key"  : "congi1",
                           "values" :[
                                   {
                                    "key" :"date1",
                                    "value": 12
                                   }
                              ],
                            
                           },
                           {
                            "key"  : "congi2",
                            "values" :[
                                    {
                                      "key"  : "date1",
                                      "value": 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "key"  : "date3",
                                      "value": 14
                                    }
                                    ],
                               
                             }
                             ],
                          
                    },
                    {
                     "key"  : "projct2_prortfolio_23",
                     "values" :[
                              {
                                "key"  : "congi1",
                                "values" :[
                                          {
                                           "key"  : "date2",
                                           "value" :1
                                          },
                                          {
                                           "key"  : "date3",
                                            "value": 10
                                           }
                                         ],
                              
                               }
                               ],
                          
                      }
                      ]  ,
      
        }
           ]

var rangeBands = [];
var cummulative = 0; // to get transform position of categories 'portfolio1,portfolio2,portfolio3 on x axis scale
data.forEach(function(val, i) {  
  var valLength = 0;  // to get position of x axis for categories 'portfolio1,portfolo2,portfolio3 on x axis scale
  val.cummulative = cummulative;
  var cum = 0;  // to get trnsfrom position of categories 'projct1,project2,project3' on x axis scale
  val.values.forEach(function(values) { 
     var valLe = 0;      // to get position of x axis for categories 'projct1,project2,project3' on x axis scale
     values.cummulative2 = cum;
     values.parentKey = val.key;
     var cum3 = 0; // to get trnsfrom position of categories 'config1,config2...etc on x axis scale
    values.values.forEach(function(values) { // config level
     values.cummulative3 = cum3;
     values.parentKey = values.key;
    values.values.forEach(function(values) { 
        cum3 = cum3 +1; 
        valLe = valLe + 1;
        cum = cum+1;
        valLength = valLength +1 ;
        cummulative = cummulative+1;
       values.parentKey = values.key;
      rangeBands.push(i);
    })
   })
   values.valueLength2 = valLe;
  })
val.valueLength = valLength; 
});



// set x axis domain adn range
var x_category = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width]);
var x_defect = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(rangeBands).rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var x_category_domain = x_defect.rangeBand() * rangeBands.length*3;
x_category.domain([0, x_category_domain]);


// y axis domain and range
var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(cat) {
  return d3.max(cat.values, function(def) {
    return d3.max(def.values, function(def) {
     return d3.max(def.values, function(def) {
      return def.value;
      });
    });
  });
})]);



// x axis scale
var category_axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x_category)
  .orient("bottom");


// y axis scale
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .style('background-color', 'EFEFEF')
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Value");


//add all category groups of 'profolio1,portfolio2,portfolio3 ..etc for svg
var category_g = svg.selectAll(".category")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category category-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x_category((d.cummulative * x_defect.rangeBand())) + ",0)";
  });


//add all category groups of projct1,project2 etc for every category group of category_g
var category_g1 = category_g.selectAll(".category1")
    .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category category1-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x_category((d.cummulative2 * x_defect.rangeBand())) + ",0)";
  })

//add all category groups of 'congif1,config2' etc for every category group of category_g1
var category_g2 = category_g1.selectAll(".category2")
    .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category category2-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x_category((d.cummulative3 * x_defect.rangeBand())) + ",0)";
  })
 


// lables for category_g
var category_label = category_g.selectAll(".category-label")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category-label category-label-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var x_label = x_category((d.valueLength * x_defect.rangeBand() + barPadding) / 2);
    var y_label = height + 120;
    return "translate(" + x_label + "," + y_label + ")";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');


// lines to separate each category_g labels
category_g.append("line")
.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return x_category((d.valueLength * x_defect.rangeBand()+ barPadding));
})  
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("x2", function(d) {
    return x_category((d.valueLength * x_defect.rangeBand()+ barPadding));
})  
.attr("y2", 120)
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    var x_label = 0;
    var y_label = height;
    return "translate(" + x_label + "," + y_label + ")";
  })
.style("stroke-width", 1)
.style("stroke", "red")
.style("fill", "none");



// lables for category_g1
var category_label1 = category_g1.selectAll(".category-label1")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category-label category-label-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var x_label = x_category((d.values.length * x_defect.rangeBand()+ barPadding) / 2);
    var y_label = height + 80;
    return "translate(" + x_label + "," + y_label + ")";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');

// lines to separate each category_g1 labels

category_g1.append("line")
.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return x_category((d.valueLength2* x_defect.rangeBand()+ barPadding));
})  
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("x2", function(d) {
    return x_category((d.valueLength2 * x_defect.rangeBand()+ barPadding));
})   
.attr("y2", 80)
 .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var x_label = 0;
    var y_label = height;
    return "translate(" + x_label + "," + y_label + ")";
  })
.style("stroke-width", 1)
.style("stroke", "blue")
.style("fill", "none");


// lables for category_g2
var category_label2 = category_g2.selectAll(".category-label2")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'category-label category-label2-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var x_label = x_category((d.values.length * x_defect.rangeBand()) / 2);
    var y_label = height + 50;
    return "translate(" + x_label + "," + y_label + ")";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');


// lines to separate each category_g2 labels

category_g2.append("line")
.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return x_category((d.values.length* x_defect.rangeBand()+ barPadding));
})  
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("x2", function(d) {
    return x_category((d.values.length * x_defect.rangeBand()+ barPadding));
})   
.attr("y2", 60)
 .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var x_label = 0;
    var y_label = height;
    return "translate(" + x_label + "," + y_label + ")";
  })
.style("stroke-width", 1)
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("fill", "none");


// lables for defect_g
var defect_g = category_g2.selectAll(".defect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return 'defect defect-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x_category((i * x_defect.rangeBand())) + ",0)";
  });

var defect_label = defect_g.selectAll(".defect-label")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
   
    return 'defect-label defect-label-' + d.key;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var x_label = x_category((x_defect.rangeBand() + barPadding) / 2);
    var y_label = height + 10;
    return "translate(" + x_label + "," + y_label + "),rotate(-90)";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');


var rects = defect_g.selectAll('.rect')
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("width", x_category(x_defect.rangeBand() - barPadding))
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x_category(barPadding);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  });


// to display values on top of bar chart
  defect_g.selectAll("text.bar")
      .data(function(d) {
    
    return [d];
  })
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "rect1")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x_category(x_defect.rangeBand()-barPadding)/2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .text(function(d) { return d.value+"%"; });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `rotating labels` will do good with area without overlapping.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

or in order to `wrap text`:

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
      .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here are examples of :

1. Rotating axis labels : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522
2. Wrapping axis labels : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Comment: Graph will not look good if we rotate every level labels.And it is difficult to understand which group is belongs to which if we rotate labels of every level

Comment: Well I have also answered how to wrap axis labels too in above answer

Comment: above text wrap will work for labels have names as combination of words separated with spaces

Comment: Above `wrap` funciton is an implementation you can modify it as per your need isn't it

Comment: Just replace `words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),` with may be underscore `words = text.text().split("_").reverse(),`

Comment: we can change words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse() according to requirement.But my problem is if text.text() don't have any spaces and underscore.only set of characters.then how can i wrap that text ?for that i need pixel width occupied by that text.text().how to get pixel width of specific string in above case?

Comment: Yes and thats why I said you need to handle as per your requirement. for example there is no pattern to split you could simply split every 5 or 6 characters as much as you can show in the line without overlapping you can do that like `text.text().match(/.{3}|.{1,2}/g);`. Here is an example of that `http://jsfiddle.net/ReRPz/1/`

Comment: Well there is no exact solution for this then. At some point it will break for example you have 1000 bars to show on a mobile screen I think even text wrapping cant save overlapping as it cannot even accomodate single character per line without overlap. So you need to think of alternatives for example if data is more you can think of a `horizontal scoll` to the chart so nothing breaks . Here is an example how to do that http://bl.ocks.org/MartynJones87/raw/7db0d637e178e7204c0a/